# Vanilla js fadeIn animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to animate a fade in effect with vanilla js, but the animated element isn't keeping opacity 1. It shows very short but dissapears right after.

```
var carousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');
window.onload = function() {
    carousel.style.opacity = 0;
    (function fadeIn() {
        console.log('timer working');
        (carousel.style.opacity += .1) > 1 ? carousel.style.opacity = 1 : setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000)
    })();
}
```

The timeout function is working, but I don't get why the element isn't keeping opacity 1 when it has reached 1.

Comment: It's preferable to either use CSS or requestAnimationFrame when animating HTML objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`carousel.style.opacity` is a string, that's why you need to parse it at some point. To improve readability I would also avoid using such a complex ternary operator in favour of early return:

```
window.onload = function() {
    carousel.style.opacity = 0;
    (function fadeIn() {
        var opacity = parseFloat(carousel.style.opacity);

        if (opacity == 1) return;

        carousel.style.opacity = opacity + 0.1;
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000);
    })();
};
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xowasiyoti/2/

Answer (score 2):

It's because CSS properties are stored internally as strings, so in this case the += is appending .1 as a string.

That's why the first increment works: '0' + '.1' === '0.1', but subsequent increments are invalid and are ignored ('0.1' + '.1' === '0.1.1').

If you manually cast style.opacity to a float it works:

```js
var carousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');
window.onload = function() {
    carousel.style.opacity = 0;
    (function fadeIn() {
        console.log('timer working');
        (carousel.style.opacity = parseFloat(carousel.style.opacity) + .1) > 1 ? carousel.style.opacity = 1 : setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000)
    })();
}
```

```css
#myCarousel {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel"></div>
```

Comment: Upvote for pointing out that string concatenation is happening instead of addition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it's working at all. Remember that **style values are strings**, so `+=` will probably not do what you expect. Try putting `console.log(carousel.style.opacity + 0 + 0 + 0)` in the function. You'll most likely see those superfluous zeroes.

So, for this to work, you'll have to convert the string to a number, and because you're using decimals, you'll have to use `parseFloat()`.

There is such a thing as too much brevity. Shoehorning all the logic into a single ternary operator is going to be tricky (but possible). Here's an example which does what you're looking for, with the extra lines making the code more legible IMO:

```
var carousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');
window.onload = function() {
    carousel.style.opacity = 0;
    (function fadeIn() {
        var o = parseFloat(carousel.style.opacity);
        (o += .1) > 1 ? o = 1 : setTimeout(fadeIn, 1000)
        carousel.style.opacity = String(o);
    })();
}
```

Also, consider using a CSS transition instead. So much easier, and no timeout needed.

```
/* should be in a stylesheet */

#myCarousel {
    transition:10s;
}


/* should be in a script */

var carousel = document.getElementById('myCarousel');
window.onload = function() {
    carousel.style.opacity = 1;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why calculating everything with JS.
CSS may be your anwser ;)

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
function toggle() {
  test.classList.toggle('fadeIn');
}
```

```css
#test {
  -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
  transition: 1s opacity;
  opacity: 1;
}
#test.fadeIn {
  opacity: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Text
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle fade</button>
```